# Monitor is switched off after 60 seconds of inactivity

Tags: display

I have upgraded CPU on my laptop to i7-2760QM and after that have side effect.
Windows **power** and **battery** settings have no affect and monitor switching off anyway.
Monitor keeps working only when playing video like Youtube or Netflix, otherwise is switching off after 60 seconds.

Is there are anything that can be done to fix that?

Comment: Perhaps update the BIOS (UEFI) and then Power Drivers after that.

Comment: Not only what @John says .. look in the UEFI settings too for power settings.  Sometimes they seem to override the ones in windows even thought that isn't supposed to happen.